# How to run parallel blocking jobs in Jenkins with different outcome

Tags: jenkins

I'm using parameterized trigger to run parallel jobs A and B. The problem is that if A fails, I want the build to fail, but if B fails, I want the build to be unstable. Is there a way to configure parameterized trigger for this or wrap it in a different plugin that would make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Workflow](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to do this.

```
parallel a: {
    build 'a'
}, b: {
    def r = build job: 'b', propagate: false
    if (r.result != 'SUCCESS') {
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
    }
}
```